# package bigvis does not install on windows 7 machine

Tags: r, installation, package, visualization

when trying to install the bigvis package [Hadley,2013] in R 3.0.1 on a Windows 7 32 bit machine, i get the following message:

```
> library(devtools)    
> devtools::install_github("bigvis")
  Installing github repo(s) bigvis/master from hadley
  Installing bigvis.zip from https://github.com/hadley/bigvis/archive/master.zip
  Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

what could this be? [i had no issues on a linux debian system].
[internet connection works]

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your internet connection. Are you behind a firewall/proxy server?

Comment: Hi Paul, internet connection works [edited question]. installed an other package - that did not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me as well, it was the proxy, you can try this :

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="your_url", port=port_you_use))
```

Comment: that represents the solution to *a* network connection problem.  Do you know if it was the same problem as the OP had??

Comment: I was able to install packages in the normal way via `install.packages()`, but via `devtools` i have the same error than Henk : `couldn't connect to host`, this solution fixed it for me, so why not try?